# Criando relatórios com ASP.NET MVC e AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, relatório

Meu *backend* é com `C#`/`MVC`, no *frontend* uso `Angular`, cheguei num ponto do projeto que preciso criar relatórios.
Como gerar relatórios em ambiente web?
Qual ferramenta que usa?

Comment: Sua pergunta é meio ampla. Você precisa fazer uma pesquisa pois há enumeras ferramentas e formas de fazer relatórios, que vão de relatórios em HTML(tables) até com ferramentas pagas ou gratuitas como Report Viewer, Crystal Reports, Active Reports entre outras tantas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o [ng-report](http://desmart.com/blog/ng-report-front-end-development-made-easier-with-angularjs/)
Ou então o [wijmo-5](http://wijmo.com/products/wijmo-5/)

Isto, se do lado do Front End.

Comment: o que vc aconseha, do lado do front ou do back ? qual a principal diferença

Comment: Aconselho do lado do BackEnd. 
reduzes o tamanho de dados a serem enviados para o FrontEnd e se necessitares de usar esses mesmo dados em uma outra parte do FrontEnd ou um outro aplicativo não tens de voltar a replicar o mesmo  código logico para obter os mesmos  valores.